# append data into the state array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to append data.rate into the this.state.test after iterating over the value, the problem is that the data is not showing in test

```js
export default class LiveApiData extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { ndata: [], test: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ ndata: data }));
  }

  render() {
    let x = this.state.ndata.map((data) => this.setState({ test: data.rate }));
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> {x} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Sample of my api after console.log

```
0:{timestamp:"2018-04-14T00:00:00Z",rate:"7999.09816231845214650049179249741253"}
►1:{timestamp:"2018-04-15T00:00:00Z",rate:"8357.6586830697213301743207363910892"}
►2:{timestamp:"2018-04-16T00:00:00Z",rate:"8046.07792934854261706414967686716349"}
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: @Irfanwani the problem is the test in the this.state is not showing nothing

Comment: Is the data successfully saving to the ndata state array initially on mount? Is the sample data, the structure of the object response?

Comment: @twominds yes it is.

Comment: Does the response come in as an array of objects?

Comment: @twominds yes it does

Comment: First of all you should not write the logic inside the render function. write it in some method and call it on some button click or at the component did mount. And while setting the test, first check if you are getting the ndata because it takes some time which creates the problem

Comment: Is the console.log() of your sample data, after it enters your front end. Meaning, have you tried creating a variable of the response data and then console.log()'ing it?

Comment: Exactly what do you want your code to achieve?

Comment: @TayyabMazhar i want to receive data from my api, after that i want to append the rate from the object into the this.state.test

Comment: And you are trying to do that in .then(..) call. Correct?

Comment: yes exactly @TayyabMazhar

Comment: @code_novice_1234 check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `data` received in `then` call is an array of object, and each object contains **rate**

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
              const ndata = data
              const test = data.map((element)=>element.rate)

              this.setState({ndata:ndata, test:test})
           });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your test is just a derived value of your state then you don't a state for it.

```
export default class LiveApiData extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { ndata: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ ndata: data }));
  }

  render() {
    let x = this.state.ndata.map((data) => { test: data.rate });
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> {x} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Not `x` here is an [] so might need to map it as below

```
 {x.map(({test}, index) => <Text key={index}> {test} </Text>)}
```